# How can I use the Iterator design pattern to provide multiple iterators for a wrapper container class in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator, containers

I am really a noob in C++, so please don't mind if my question shows lack of basic knowledge.
I have a class User that describes a user in my system. It contains simple fields, like `string name`, `string email`, `int age`, etc.
I also have a wrapper class Group that uses an `std::list` in order to store a collection of Users. What I want to do is to use the Iterator design pattern in order to provide two different iterators for the Group class. By using one of the iterators, I want to be able to go through the list sorted by the User's name and by using the other one I want to do same thing, except that it should be sorted by the User's age.

I read this article (https://www.robertlarsononline.com/2017/04/24/iterator-pattern-using-cplusplus/) on the Iterator design pattern but I'm not sure on how I can adapt the shown code to my case. I am guessing that my Group class needs to have two `CreateIterator()` methods (i.e: `CreateAgeIterator()` and `CreateNameIterator()`), each one returning a different specialization of the Iterator class. The problem is that I don't know where exactly I should put the logic of sorting the list according to a specific criterion.
This is just a basic project that I am doing to study a little bit of the language as well as the Iterator design pattern itself. I am not concerned with being STL compliant or anything, I just need a simple implementation of the concept.

Comment: AFAICS, you are basically asking to write us code for you, which is not going to happen. Also, the link you posted is very unidiomatic for C++ and in my opinion a terrible way of approaching the problem. Look into `<algorithm>` and lambdas instead.

Comment: Also `std::list` is almost certainly not the container you want.  It is a double-linked list, not the contiguous `List` class provded by C# or Java.  Unless you have a good reason for choosing otherwise, you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: Finally iterators in C++ come in pairs (begin and end) - a C++ iterator does not know when it has reached the end of the container.  So you would want `age_begin()`, `age_end()`, `name_begin()`, and `name_end()`.

Comment: @MartinBonner, ok, I can change my code so that it uses `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, I came from Java, so I thought `std::list` would be equivalent. Also, can you elaborate on the whole pair thing?

Comment: @ViníciusSilva `std::list` is roughly equivalent to LinkedList in Java. How often have you used LinkedList?

Comment: A fairly idiomattic way to use your group in C++ would be: `for (auto it = group.age_begin(); it != group.age_end(); ++it) { do_stuff(*it); }`.  There are algorithms which can wrap that into a single statement, but the basic approach is that a range is defined by a *pair* of iterators - not a single iterator which knows where the end is.

Comment: As Vittorio hinted, you can use sort from `<algorithm>` to sort your list by a given comperator. This way you can sort your list by name or age. Then `std::vector` provides functions `begin` and `end`, which gives you iterators over the vector.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I am not asking you to write code for me. What I want to know is where I should include the code for sorting the list based on the approach you called terrible. I am also open for other sources that better show an implementation of the Iterator design pattern. The one I posted was the simplest one I found.

Comment: What you want is already implemented in Boost.multiindex - which provides multiple container interfaces for the same data (so you can get different set of iterators). But this library has learning curve and is not novice friendly.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy yes, sorting the list is not my main concern. What I am really interested in is how to use the Iterator Design Pattern, so providing a comparator to an `algorithm` wouldn't help me to understand the concept I need.

Comment: @ViníciusSilva I'd search for "implement iterator in C++". Drop the "pattern" part, since iterators in C++ don't use interface and inheritance to solve this. Check for "forward iterator" which is the type concept used in generic code.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to go through the list sorted by the User's name and by using the other one I want to do same thing, except that it should be sorted by the User's age.

In order to iterate a list in a sorted order, the list must be sorted according to that order. But a list can only have one order.

One solution for two orderings is to sort the list using one order, and have another data structure, which contains pointers to the list elements, but sorted using the other ordering.

Note that the iterators of this other container don't point to the elements of the list directly, but instead to the pointers. As such, using the iterators of the pointer container itself is not the same as using iterators to the list that contains the elements.

> The problem is that I don't know where exactly I should put the logic of sorting the list according to a specific criterion.

Enforce the the ordering whenever elements are inserted or removed.

Note that the elements of the list should be const so that you cannot break the ordering by modifying the state of the objects.